# Running the WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 on local machine givers an error, even i changed the offset in Carbon.xml

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

> Hi,
>
> i am running the WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 in my local machine , i changed the
>   offset in carbon.xml,still it gives the error as
>
> 1. [2013-10-25 17:48:00,975] ERROR - JMXServerManager Could not initialize RMI server java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in
>      use: 11113; nested exception is:      java.net.BindException: Address
>      already in use
> 2. ERROR - CarbonTomcat LifeCycleException while starting tomcat connector org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>      component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-9445]]
>
> Help me to figure out this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have some other programs running that listen on these ports. Try to find out the corresponding processes, e.g., using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) if you're on Windows, and see whether you can stop them. Alternatively, you may try to increase the offset until you stumble upon some free ports.

Comment: I am working on Linux Ubuntu, How could i solve same problem on this.Can you explain in detail

Comment: You should be able to find identify the programs running on the ports needd by WSO2 by using 'netstat' or 'lsof'. However, I'm not familiar with Linux, so I cannot help much further.
Anyhow, you can still scan for open ports and then adjust the offset in carbon.xml so the ESB will use them.